# How can I know where to shoot a projectile to make it hit a point?

Tags: rotations

I have got two objects in a world. One of them is an archer, and I would like him to shoot the other one in a 3D space.

How do I know what X, Y, and Z velocities to give the arrow? I obviously know about sines and cosines and stuff, but for some reason I seem to be unable to work out how to use them to do this.

Comment: Sorry about the short post. I couldn't work out how to make it any better. I'm incredibly tired, since I've been programming all day.

Comment: If you are working in 2D then this page on wikipedia about projectile motion will help, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion

Comment: @Vikram It's in 3D space.

Comment: Is gravity involved?  Are the objects moving?  If not, the velocities just need to be some number times the difference in coordinates.  If that number is $1$, the arrow will get there in one time unit.